# How can i match each /proc/net/tcp entry to each opened socket?

Tags: c, linux, networking, procfs

I'm trying to parse socket info from `/proc/net/tcp` and while I can identify some fields, such as memory addresses or send queue use, I can't find how each entry is bound to its socket descriptor. e.g., with this data:

```
1: 5922140A:E459 D5C43B45:0050 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 507218 1 f6ab1300 57 3 12 4 -1
```

I want to know which is the correspondant socket descriptor.

Comment: Do you mean file descriptor number for the owning process, or do you want to know the process that owns a given socket?

Comment: @MattJoiner - Hi Matt, How to know the process that owns a given socket?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take the inode number (in this case, 507218).  Each open file descriptor to that socket (there may be multiple file descriptors for the same socket) will appear as a link of the form:

```
/proc/<PID>/fd/<N> -> socket[507218]
```

(where `<PID>` is the process ID and `<N>` is the file descriptor).