# XCode Objective-C Shell Script Command

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell

I have a custom script that will be bundled (or compiled) in my application that would normally take an argument such as:

```
# command argument
```

How do I call it (with the argument) when the application starts and have it continue running in the background until the application quits?

Answer (score 1):

If it's Mac OS X you can use an `NSThread`. In that thread you can launch the task with `NSTask`.

If you're on iOS you can still use `NSThread` but you'll need a replacement for `NSTask`. The code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692831/262660) can be used on iOS.