# Check number of correctly received packets - Socket Programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, wireless

I am writing an application in C using socket programming. I wish to send the data from the server node to the client node. I use the read and write commands on the socket descriptor to get and send the data over the network respectively. Since, the underlying protocol used is TCP/IP, finally I receive the correct data. Is it possible to check on the client side that to receive the data correctly, how many packets were actually lost and re-transmitted? I am writing this application in Linux (debian) environment.

Any help is highly appreciated !

-Rahulkumar

Comment: If you want to confirm that the data is correct, then also send a checksum (e.g. SHA1).  Of course, there's no system that's 100% foolproof...

Comment: "how many packets were actually lost and re-transmitted" - there's no way with the posix socket interface... I guess it's doable with tcpdump/wireshark.

Comment: Well, Thanks  Oli Charlesworth and  Karoly Horvath. There might be some way in my opinion, since wireshark tool, in its implementation must have used some API's to check the number of re-transmitted packets. I shall check the details of tcpdump. Thanks again.

Comment: both are using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/proc/net/tcp` has a field `retrnsmt`, you simply need to [find your socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319521/how-can-i-match-each-proc-net-tcp-entry-to-each-opened-socket) in this list.

An alternative would be to use the [`TCP_INFO` sockopt](http://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html). The current layout of `struct tcp_info` can be found in [linux/tcp.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h#L148). The field you want to use is probably `tcpi_retrans`.

Comment: Wow, That's really cool stuff.. Thank you nemo and Karoly Horvath. I need to figure out the way to use it. Will update you guys after successfully completing it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget upvoting/accepting the answer if it worked for you so it's not dangling around as unanswered :)

Comment: @nemo , I am sorry, can u please let me know how to up-vote the answer if you don't mind ? Actually, white votingup, it says about the minimum reputation needed to vote up. Will surely do when my reputation goes up, I joined today :)

Comment: @RahulkumarThakkar You can vote answers up as soon as you've gained 15 reputation. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation for further reading. Welcome to SO btw. ;)